# How do I access the variable name of an object that is a function argument in Javascript with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var myObj = {
  key: "element",
  key2: "element2"
}    

function stuff(obj) {
  var a = obj;
  console.log(a);
}
stuff(myObj);
```

How do I make stuff(myObj) console.log myObj, which is the name of the object? If I were to run this code, it would print that the argument myObj passed into stuff is an object and console.log its keys and elements. I want var a to store and console.log the name of the object instead of its contents, which in this case, is myObj.

Comment: jQuery is irrevant here

Comment: what is the name of the object? if you are referring to `myObj` it is the name of the variable.

Comment: Why do you want so ? `variable` is nothing but a reference, it has nothing to do with the values of the object...

Comment: @RayonDabre I'm trying to change the text of an html tag that has an id that has the same name of the object's name, so I was wondering if it were possible to iterate through each element of an object and change the html tag's text to a specific element in the object using a for-in loop using jQuery's selector .text

Comment: That's the question you should have asked ^^^ :)

Comment: You can't get the variable name, but you *can* give the object itself a name property.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. JavaScript passes by value, there is no connection to the variable that was used to pass the object.

Take this example:

```
var foo = {};
var bar = foo;
window.baz = bar;
stuff(foo);
function stuff(obj) {
  var a = obj;
  console.log(a);
}
```

You now have 5 variables / properties which are **all** "names" for the same object.

If you need an object to have some kind of identifying name, then give it as a property.

```
var foo = { name: "foo" };
```

Comment: Javascript passes objects by reference, not by value. That's the only reason why those 5 variables are indeed all names for the very same object.

Comment: @EricJ.Francois — The value of `foo` is a reference to the object. That value gets passed. It doesn't pass a reference to `foo`.

Answer (score 0):

> Use `for-in` loop to iterate through object. `a` and `b` are keys of the object which are mapped to `id` of the elements..

Try this:

```js
var obj = {
  a: "A",
  b: "B"
};
for (var i in obj) {
  $('#' + i).hide();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="a">A</div>
<div id="b">B</div>
<div id="c">C</div>
<div id="d">D</div>
```

Comment: The question is asking how to get `obj` not `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible! You can do something like this:

```
function stuff(obj) {
  var a = Object.keys(window);
  a.forEach(function(item, i, a) {
    if (window[item] == obj)
    {
       console.log((item);
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no (good) way to do that. The myObj variable has a pointer to the object in the memory. When you send myObj as parameter to a function, it will be sent by reference, so the obj parameter of your function will also have the pointer to the object in memory.
At this point the global variable myObj and local variable obj are synonyms for the same object. Modifying the property of one will also affect the other variable.
Theoretically there could be hundreds of variables pointing to the same object, but the object would never have any link back to any of the variables that point to it, so there is no way to retrieve the name of an object. There is no correct or original variable: all variables are identical no matter in what order they were linked to this object.

This said, of course if myObj is a global variable, it would be possible to compare your variable with all properties of the window object and then know which variable it was originally, but that's an awful waste of processing power. And it will only work with global variables.

So this should do the trick for global variable, but I strongly advise against doing this (most of all if it's a big project with lots of global variables). Still, if used during coding for debugging only, which I assume this is all about, it might be of some help:

```
function getVariableName(x) {
    for (var i in window) {
        if (window[i] === x) return i;
    }
    return false;
}
```

**Attention:** if you got more than one global variable pointing to this object, there is no way to know which of those variable names you will get back ... javascript does not define a fix order of enumerating properties of an object. The first match will be reported back!